# set div width to fit the content

Tags: css, sass

I tried creating a button. I didn't set the width so it should automatically increase the width when I add a margin to the div or the svg, but it just scales it down and hides the overflow.

```
.btn {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background: none;
    margin: 0.5% 0;
    padding: .8%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    gap: 20%;

    &:hover {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
      border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
    }

    &:hover.disabled {
      background: none;
      border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }

    &.disabled {
      cursor: default;
      color: gray;
    }

    & svg {
      background: none;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 100%;
    }

    & div {
      font-size: 100%;
    }

  }
```

Comment: [`width:fit-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)?

Comment: it's probably a `box-sizing` issue

Comment: please edit your question and put CSS (not sass) + HTML and make it a runnable code so we could inspect the situation because currently it's very unclear

Answer (score 0):

Tested the following code on Firefox, and it works as expected. I do not understand what is the problem you are facing, and on what browser.
Also, since, you did not provide any information about the `div` inside your `button`, I left it as an empty element. As a result, the `div` occupies zero width for its content - since it has no content inside of it. Although, padding and margin on the div should work.
Plus, I set `box-sizing: border-box` on everything using the wildcard selector, since it makes visualizing layout boxes a bit intuitive.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0.5% 0;
  padding: 0.8%;
  
  /* Changed the border color, so we can see the button size grow */
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  gap: 20%;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.btn:hover.disabled {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.btn.disabled {
  cursor: default;
  color: gray;
}

.btn svg {
  background: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;

  /* Adding margin to check if everything is working fine */
  margin: 10px;
}

.btn div {
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <button class="btn">
  <svg width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
    <path d="M15 2V1H3v1H0v4c0 1.6 1.4 3 3 3v1c.4 1.5 3 2.6 5 3v2H5s-1 1.5-1 2h10c0-.4-1-2-1-2h-3v-2c2-.4 4.6-1.5 5-3V9c1.6-.2 3-1.4 3-3V2h-3ZM3 7c-.5 0-1-.5-1-1V4h1v3Zm8.4 2.5L9 8 6.6 9.4l1-2.7L5 5h3l1-2.7L10 5h2.8l-2.3 1.8 1 2.7h-.1ZM16 6c0 .5-.5 1-1 1V4h1v2Z"
    ></path>
  </svg>
  <div></div>
</button>
```